# Symfony: make CSRF token available to all twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig, csrf

My app has AJAX requests here and there, and I want to protect them with CSRF tokens. However, rather than generating and passing a CSRF token to the Twig renderer for use in the JavaScript, I'd like a CSRF token to be readily available in every html page that Twig renders.

I've seen that Laravel seems to put it in a meta tag, so I can easily grab it with JavaScript. But how to do this in Symfony? How can I insert this token in every page?

Or is this not good practice?

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: I need it to secure my AJAX requests

Comment: found it, I can insert the tokenmanager as a twig global variable in config.yml, then call the tokenmanager from the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is a good practice!!

You have the built-in function `csrf_token('key')` in symfony/twig for that.

Example:

```
<a href="{{ path('product_remove', {id: product.id, csrf: csrf_token('product') }) }}" 
   class="btn btn-info">Remove</a>
```

From a controller, you just have to check it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/product/remove/{csrf}/{id}", name="product_remove")
 */
public function removeProductAction($csrf, $id)
{
    if ($csrf !== $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('product')->getValue()) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token');
    }

    // delete $id

    // cleans up url
    return $this->redirectToRoute('product_list');
}
```

[image: all the things]

Comment: noooo~ are you serious? I had searched the internet all afternoon and thought inserting the service and then calling it was pretty clever. Turns out all I had to do is call csrf_token() in Twig. Dunno how I missed it.

rarr all the things.

edit: I mean thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer: insert it as a twig global variable and then use Javascript to bind it to all requests.

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    ## ...
    globals:
        csrfTokenManager:  '@security.csrf.token_manager'
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', '{{ csrfTokenManager.getToken('ajaxAuth') }}');
    });
</script>
```

**Receiving controller**

```
public function receiveAction (Request $request)
{
    $tokenManager = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
    $tokenId = 'ajaxAuth';
    $token = new CsrfToken($tokenId, $request->headers->get('x-csrf-token'));

    if (!$tokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
        throw new HttpException(403, 'Go away h4x0r');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to use same token id everywhere? What is the point of the token id parameter then if it is same everywhere?